# Double entry accounting database design

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, database-design

Simple question

See http://homepages.tcp.co.uk/~m-wigley/gc_wp_ded.html

Ok there are 3 tables ACCOUNT, JOURNAL, and POSTING

If you want to have a transaction status, where should the status column be?

1. Status should be in the Journal table
2. Status should be in the Posting table

please explain your choice, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, but trick question?  There is no requirement for a success/failure status because a JOURNAL is a logical unit of work, and all of its POSTINGs are part of that unit of work.  Therefore the JOURNAL and its POSTINGS either exist, if the logical unit of work is successful, or they don't exist if the unit of work is unsuccessful.

This simple test (it's there because it worked or it's not there because it didn't) is a consequence of the fact that there is a business requirement to ensure that JOURNAL includes a candidate key comprised of an unbroken sequence of numbers, which is necessary because it gives auditors a false sense of security.

In a real-world system, there would be a second set of tables, along the lines of PENDING_BATCH, PENDING_JOURNAL and PENDING_POSTING which would contain transactions that haven't been completed yet.  It would make sense to keep various kinds of status information here.  The transaction status for pending transactions belongs on the PENDING_JOURNAL table because the whole journal and all of its postings must either succeed or fail as a unit, so the status of the unit should be normalized to the parent record (i.e. PENDING_JOURNAL).

Comment: What about if you put the status in Journal? only post it to POSTING table when its final?

Comment: I don't know how that would work.  You need to have POSTING records right from the start because that's how you know which amounts went into which ACCOUNTs.  If you read all the way down to the end of that link you provided, you'll see that the author also points out that you need to have a separate set of tables for pending work.

Comment: you mean the batch table? "The concept of a Batch is also useful for electronic data transfer as it provides a method of aggregation for audit trail and correction processing. As a rule it is sensible to keep the details of ‘unauthorised’ entries in separate tables from those ‘pucker’ double entries made by the ‘authorisation’ process into the POSTING table. "

Comment: You could most definitely have a status code on the PENDING_BATCH table too.  However, I would still maintain status at the PENDING_JOURNAL table whether you keep it at the batch level or not.  A journal and all of its postings must be part of a transaction wrapper because they must all be there (or none be there) for the database to be semantically consistent.  Therefore the status of this lowest level transaction is important.  A BATCH could conceivably contain thousands or even millions of journals.  I would never build a database transaction wrapper that large - it is totally impractical.

Comment: Hello Joel, you said you will never build a build a transaction wrapper that large? What do you mean by this? you dont like the design? I found someone else's design, however it is wrong, you cant track the double entry accounting http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/accounting_systems/index.htm so that is even worst :(

Comment: If you create a transaction wrapper that wraps too many transactions, then you end up escalating record and page locks into table locks - all of which take a long time to clear.  This blocks other work and can be impractical in a production system.  Also, it can be pretty wasteful if one little problem with one transaction undoes many, many good transactions.  This is why I would say that huge transaction wrappers are impractical.  Regarding your link, I agree that the model is not sufficient.  To be honest, that site is referenced a lot but I'm not always impressed with their models.